# Denormilize XML and group by value of a child in XSL

Tags: xslt-1.0

I intend to "denormalize" and group by value of an element in a child.
Try to : identify the groups (based on GoupID element)
         create output group elements, containing all related info from the initial parent

Initial sample (the real one does conatains far more elements) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListOfBIPIncident>
    <Incident>
        <IncidentId>1</IncidentId>
        <Element1>Value of element 1 in incidentId = 1 </Element1>
        <Element2>Value of element 2 in incidentId = 1 </Element2>
        <ListOfDetails>
            <Space1>Space of 1</Space1>
            <Space2>Space of 2</Space2>
        </ListOfDetails>
        <ListOfElementsToGroupBy>
            <Group_Me>
                <GroupID>100</GroupID>
                <GroupName>Name of group 100</GroupName>
                <DateOf>12/12/2002</DateOf>
            </Group_Me>
            <Group_Me>
                <GroupID>101</GroupID>
                <GroupName>Name of group 101</GroupName>
                <DateOf>1/1/2012</DateOf>
            </Group_Me>
        </ListOfElementsToGroupBy>
        <ListOfOtherDetails>
            <Other1>Which One</Other1>
            <Other2>Which Two</Other2>
        </ListOfOtherDetails>
    </Incident>
    <Incident>
        <IncidentId>3</IncidentId>
        <Element1>Value of element 1 in incidentId = 3 </Element1>
        <Element2>Value of element 2 in incidentId = 3 </Element2>
        <ListOfDetails>
            <Space1>Space of 1 3</Space1>
            <Space2>Space of 2 3</Space2>
        </ListOfDetails>
        <ListOfElementsToGroupBy>
            <Group_Me>
                <GroupID>301</GroupID>
                <GroupName>Name of group 301</GroupName>
                <DateOf>3/3/2003</DateOf>
            </Group_Me>
        </ListOfElementsToGroupBy>
        <ListOfOtherDetails>
            <Other1>Which One 3</Other1>
            <Other2>Which Two 3</Other2>
        </ListOfOtherDetails>
    </Incident>
    <Incident>
        <IncidentId>2</IncidentId>
        <Element1>Value of element 1 in incidentId = 2 </Element1>
        <Element2>Value of element 2 in incidentId = 2 </Element2>
        <ListOfDetails>
            <Space1>Space of 1 2</Space1>
            <Space2>Space of 2 2</Space2>
        </ListOfDetails>
        <ListOfElementsToGroupBy>
            <Group_Me>
                <GroupID>101</GroupID>
                <GroupName>Name of group 101</GroupName>
                <DateOf>2/2/2009</DateOf>
            </Group_Me>
            <Group_Me>
                <GroupID>401</GroupID>
                <GroupName>Name of group 401</GroupName>
                <DateOf>5/5/2039</DateOf>
            </Group_Me>
        </ListOfElementsToGroupBy>
        <ListOfOtherDetails>
            <Other1>Which One 2</Other1>
            <Other2>Which Two 2</Other2>
        </ListOfOtherDetails>
    </Incident>
</ListOfBIPIncident>
```

Expected result:

```
<ListOfBIPIncident>
  <group name="100">
    <Incident>
      <IncidentId>1</IncidentId>
      <Element1>Value of element 1 in incidentId = 1</Element1>
      <Element2>Value of element 2 in incidentId = 1</Element2>
      <ListOfDetails>
        <Space1>Space of 1</Space1>
        <Space2>Space of 2</Space2>
      </ListOfDetails>
      <Group_Me>
        <GroupID>100</GroupID>
        <GroupName>Name of group 100</GroupName>
        <DateOf>12/12/2002</DateOf>
      </Group_Me>
      <ListOfOtherDetails>
        <Other1>Which One</Other1>
        <Other2>Which Two</Other2>
      </ListOfOtherDetails>
    </Incident>
  </group>
  <group name="101">
    <Incident>
      <IncidentId>1</IncidentId>
      <Element1>Value of element 1 in incidentId = 1</Element1>
      <Element2>Value of element 2 in incidentId = 1</Element2>
      <ListOfDetails>
        <Space1>Space of 1</Space1>
        <Space2>Space of 2</Space2>
      </ListOfDetails>
      <Group_Me>
        <GroupID>101</GroupID>
        <GroupName>Name of group 101</GroupName>
        <DateOf>1/1/2012</DateOf>
      </Group_Me>
      <ListOfOtherDetails>
        <Other1>Which One</Other1>
        <Other2>Which Two</Other2>
      </ListOfOtherDetails>
    </Incident>
    <Incident>
      <IncidentId>2</IncidentId>
      <Element1>Value of element 1 in incidentId = 2</Element1>
      <Element2>Value of element 2 in incidentId = 2</Element2>
      <ListOfDetails>
        <Space1>Space of 1 2</Space1>
        <Space2>Space of 2 2</Space2>
      </ListOfDetails>
      <Group_Me>
        <GroupID>101</GroupID>
        <GroupName>Name of group 101</GroupName>
        <DateOf>2/2/2009</DateOf>
      </Group_Me>
      <ListOfOtherDetails>
        <Other1>Which One 2</Other1>
        <Other2>Which Two 2</Other2>
      </ListOfOtherDetails>
    </Incident>
  </group>
  <group name="301">
    <Incident>
      <IncidentId>3</IncidentId>
      <Element1>Value of element 1 in incidentId = 3</Element1>
      <Element2>Value of element 2 in incidentId = 3</Element2>
      <ListOfDetails>
        <Space1>Space of 1 3</Space1>
        <Space2>Space of 2 3</Space2>
      </ListOfDetails>
      <Group_Me>
        <GroupID>301</GroupID>
        <GroupName>Name of group 301</GroupName>
        <DateOf>3/3/2003</DateOf>
      </Group_Me>
      <ListOfOtherDetails>
        <Other1>Which One 3</Other1>
        <Other2>Which Two 3</Other2>
      </ListOfOtherDetails>
    </Incident>
  </group>
  <group name="401">
    <Incident>
      <IncidentId>2</IncidentId>
      <Element1>Value of element 1 in incidentId = 2</Element1>
      <Element2>Value of element 2 in incidentId = 2</Element2>
      <ListOfDetails>
        <Space1>Space of 1 2</Space1>
        <Space2>Space of 2 2</Space2>
      </ListOfDetails>
      <Group_Me>
        <GroupID>401</GroupID>
        <GroupName>Name of group 401</GroupName>
        <DateOf>5/5/2039</DateOf>
      </Group_Me>
      <ListOfOtherDetails>
        <Other1>Which One 2</Other1>
        <Other2>Which Two 2</Other2>
      </ListOfOtherDetails>
    </Incident>
  </group>
</ListOfBIPIncident>
```

I did started something like the following which is far from what I need (and it must be in version 1.0 of xsl):

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="kEyMe" match="Group_Me"  use="GroupID" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Group_Me[generate-id()=generate-id (key('kEyMe',GroupID)[1])]">

      <group name="{GroupID}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('kEyMe',GroupID)" />
      </group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Group_Me[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('kEyMe',GroupID)[1]))]" />


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: are you looking for an XML-to-XML transform?  Have you consider extracting part of the XML using XPath instead?  Can you provide any code and describe what is the intent here?  I think XPath is much simpler, but I can be mistaken.  I need to understand more what problem needs solving.  By the way, you will have to use XPath on your XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

I think* you want something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="group-by-id" match="Group_Me" use="GroupID"/>
<xsl:key name="incident-by-group" match="Incident" use="ListOfElementsToGroupBy/Group_Me/GroupID"/>

<xsl:template match="/ListOfBIPIncident">
    <ListOfBIPIncident>
        <xsl:for-each select="Incident/ListOfElementsToGroupBy/Group_Me[generate-id()=generate-id (key('group-by-id', GroupID)[1])]">
            <group name="{GroupID}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('incident-by-group', GroupID)" />
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ListOfBIPIncident>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="group-by-id" match="Group_Me" use="GroupID"/>

<xsl:template match="/ListOfBIPIncident">
    <ListOfBIPIncident>
        <xsl:for-each select="Incident/ListOfElementsToGroupBy/Group_Me[generate-id()=generate-id (key('group-by-id',GroupID)[1])]">
            <group name="{GroupID}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('group-by-id',GroupID)/ancestor::Incident" />
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ListOfBIPIncident>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--
(*) Minimizing the example would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Michael. It looks nearly perfect. The only thing is that in the ListOfElementsToGroupBy all childs are present. It should be filtered by the group only, thus only one child (this is why I took out the list..group_me on the expected output and included only one chlid).

Comment: @IosifTanasescu That's not going to be simple. Are you sure you need this? The group is known by the (new) group parent.

Comment: I'm trying to use-it as it is (mainly I'm taking this transformation and trying to put in front of a BIPublisher report, running from Siebel), as you are right. I do have the group value which is all that I realy need from that child, all the ancestors data is denormilized corectly. Thank You again Michael.